# How can I use list for being implemented in Venn diagram?

Tags: python, machine-learning, visualization, diagram, venn-diagram

I have 4 tables and I want to see the intersections inside them. I have read 4 different tables (in excel) like this

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'E:\Mydata1.xlsx')  
df1 = pd.read_excel (r'E:\Mydata2.xlsx') 
df2 = pd.read_excel (r'E:\Mydata3.xlsx') 
df3 = pd.read_excel (r'E:\Mydata4.xlsx')
```

and then, I select only 1 column called project name that has in all tables to see the intersection like this

```
d1 = df[~df['Project Name'].isnull()].index.tolist()
d2 = df1[~df1['Project Name'].isnull()].index.tolist()
d3 = df2[~df2['Project Name'].isnull()].index.tolist() 
d4 = df3[~df3['Project Name'].isnull()].index.tolist()
```

after that, I want to use the venn library to see the venn diagram because in my case it has 4 circles and I want to see the intersections of them.

```
from venn import venn
datas = {
    "Data1": {d1},
    "Data2": {d2},
    "Data3": {d3},
    "Data4": {d4},
}
venn(datas)
```

But, I have an error message like this

```
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 12 in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from venn import venn
      2 datas = {
----> 3     "Data1": {d1},
      4     "Data2": {d2},
      5     "Data3": {d3},
      6     "Data4": {d4},
      7 }
      8 venn(datas)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I know when I've read some articles, we can't use list in hash(), But I don't know what should I do with this.
Here's the venn source https://github.com/LankyCyril/pyvenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `set` in your datas dictionary instead of `{}`.

```
datas = {
    "Data1": set(d1),
    "Data2": set(d2),
    "Data3": set(d3),
    "Data4": set(d4),
}
```

For example:

```
from venn import venn

d1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
d2 = ["B", "C", "D"]
d3 = ["A", "D", "E"]
d4 = ["C", "D", "E", "F"]

datas = {
    "Data1": set(d1),
    "Data2": set(d2),
    "Data3": set(d3),
    "Data4": set(d4),
}

venn(datas)
```

[image]